# Table doesn't reset when click on X

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have following javascript:

```
$(function(){
        $table = $('#myTable')
                .tablesorter({
                    theme: 'blue',
                    widthFixed: true,
                    headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
                    widgets: ['zebra','filter'],
                    widgetOptions: {
                        zebra: ["even", "odd"],
                        // filter_anyMatch replaced! Instead use the filter_external option
                        // Set to use a jQuery selector (or jQuery object) pointing to the
                        // external filter (column specific or any match)
                        filter_external : '.search',
                        // add a default type search to the first name column
                        filter_defaultFilter: { 1 : '~{query}' },
                        // include column filters
                        filter_columnFilters: true,
                        filter_placeholder: { search : 'Search...' },
                        filter_saveFilters : true,
                        filter_reset: '.reset'
                    }
                })
            // needed for pager plugin to know when to calculate filtered rows/pages
                .addClass('hasFilters')
                .tablesorterPager({
                    container: $(".table-pager"),
                    output: '{page} of {filteredPages} ({filteredRows})',
                    size: 5
                });

        $('#search').quicksearch('table tbody tr', {
            delay: 500,
            show: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('filtered');
                $table.trigger('pageSet'); // reset to page 1 & update display
            },
            hide: function () {
                $(this).hide().addClass('filtered');
                $table.trigger('pageSet'); // reset to page 1 & update display
            },
            onAfter: function () {
                $table.trigger('update.pager');
            }
        });
    });

    (function(b,k,q,r){b.fn.quicksearch=function(l,p){var m,n,h,e,f="",g=this,a=b.extend({delay:100,selector:null,stripeRows:null,loader:null,noResults:"",matchedResultsCount:0,bind:"keyup",onBefore:function(){},onAfter:function(){},show:function(){this.style.display=""},hide:function(){this.style.display="none"},prepareQuery:function(a){return a.toLowerCase().split(" ")},testQuery:function(a,b,d){for(d=0;d<a.length;d+=1)if(-1===b.indexOf(a[d]))return!1;return!0}},p);this.go=function(){for(var c=0,b=
            0,d=!0,e=a.prepareQuery(f),g=0===f.replace(" ","").length,c=0,k=h.length;c<k;c++)g||a.testQuery(e,n[c],h[c])?(a.show.apply(h[c]),d=!1,b++):a.hide.apply(h[c]);d?this.results(!1):(this.results(!0),this.stripe());this.matchedResultsCount=b;this.loader(!1);a.onAfter();return this};this.search=function(a){f=a;g.trigger()};this.currentMatchedResults=function(){return this.matchedResultsCount};this.stripe=function(){if("object"===typeof a.stripeRows&&null!==a.stripeRows){var c=a.stripeRows.join(" "),f=a.stripeRows.length;
        e.not(":hidden").each(function(d){b(this).removeClass(c).addClass(a.stripeRows[d%f])})}return this};this.strip_html=function(a){a=a.replace(RegExp("<[^<]+>","g"),"");return a=b.trim(a.toLowerCase())};this.results=function(c){"string"===typeof a.noResults&&""!==a.noResults&&(c?b(a.noResults).hide():b(a.noResults).show());return this};this.loader=function(c){"string"===typeof a.loader&&""!==a.loader&&(c?b(a.loader).show():b(a.loader).hide());return this};this.cache=function(){e=b(l);"string"===typeof a.noResults&&
            ""!==a.noResults&&(e=e.not(a.noResults));n=("string"===typeof a.selector?e.find(a.selector):b(l).not(a.noResults)).map(function(){return g.strip_html(this.innerHTML)});h=e.map(function(){return this});f=f||this.val()||"";return this.go()};this.trigger=function(){this.loader(!0);a.onBefore();k.clearTimeout(m);m=k.setTimeout(function(){g.go()},a.delay);return this};this.cache();this.results(!0);this.stripe();this.loader(!1);return this.each(function(){b(this).on(a.bind,function(){f=b(this).val();g.trigger()})})}})(jQuery,
                    this,document);
```

following html:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
<div class="table-pager">Show
    <select class="pagesize">
        <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>entries | <span class="pagedisplay"></span> |
    <button type="button" class="btn prev">&larr;</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn next">&rarr;</button>
</div>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
        <th>Four</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 123</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Ox</td>
        <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Girafee</td>
        <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zyx 24</td>
        <td>767</td>
        <td>Bison</td>
        <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 11</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Chimp</td>
        <td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 2</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>Elephant</td>
        <td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>155</td>
        <td>Lion</td>
        <td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC 10</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zyx 1</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.mit.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zyx 12</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>Llama</td>
        <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 111</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Ox</td>
        <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Girafee</td>
        <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zyx 24</td>
        <td>767</td>
        <td>Bison</td>
        <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 11</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Chimp</td>
        <td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 2</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>Elephant</td>
        <td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>155</td>
        <td>Lion</td>
        <td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC 10</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zyx 1</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.mit.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zyx 12</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>Llama</td>
        <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 222</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Ox</td>
        <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Girafee</td>
        <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zyx 24</td>
        <td>767</td>
        <td>Bison</td>
        <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 11</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Chimp</td>
        <td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 2</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>Elephant</td>
        <td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>155</td>
        <td>Lion</td>
        <td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC 10</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zyx 1</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.mit.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zyx 12</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>Llama</td>
        <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It works almost good. I have one issue only.

When I click `X` to reset filter - nothings to happens.

desired result - filter should reset and table should update.

Also I have a problem when I erase symbols in search field - table don't update
[image]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [quicksearch demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ZFZNF/16/) no longer works properly.

So, instead of using the quicksearch plugin, you could use the filter widget to match content in all columns:

```
<input class="search" type="search" data-column="all">
```

then include that input as an external filter, and hide the filter row

```
filter_external : '.search',
filter_columnFilters: false
```

To do the same thing, and have the "x" in the input work properly.

Full code & [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ZFZNF/100/):

```
$(function () {
    $table = $('#myTable')
        .tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            widthFixed: true,
            headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
            widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
            widgetOptions: {
                zebra: ["even", "odd"],
                filter_external: '.search',
                filter_columnFilters: false
            }
        })
        .tablesorterPager({
            container: $(".table-pager"),
            output: '{page} of {filteredPages} ({filteredRows})',
            size: 5
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have already tried adding needed plugin in head section

```
<script src="https://my-script-hosting.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.5/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.5/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.min.js"></script>
```